# setting partition count in kafka in spring boot using application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

How to set up partition count in kafka in spring boot using `application.yml`.

```yaml
kafka:
  zookeeper:
    host: localhost:2181
    groupId: group1
  topic: test_kafkaw
  bootstrap:
    servers: localhost:9092
```

Comment: What do you mean by partition count? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: You shouldn't need zookeeper connection, by the way

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Cloud Stream, you can specify partition count per Kafka topic in application.yml/application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<binding-name>.producer.partition-count
```

The Kafka binder uses the ‘partitionCount’ setting of the producer to create a topic with the given partition count.

If you are using Spring for Apache Kafka, you can use `TopicBuilder` to configure that — something like:

```
    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("topic1")
                .partitions(10)
                .replicas(1)
                .build();
    }
```

TopicBuilder reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/config/TopicBuilder.html

Comment: For the topic builder, the values can be wired in from the config, though, which is what the question was asking